# Syncing Google Calendars through iCloud

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, icloud, calendar, google-calendar

I subscribe to a bunch of Google calendars on my iPad, and I have my iPad fully set up with iOS 5 and iCloud. The only calendars that are currently syncing with iCloud are Reminders—is there any way I can also sync my Google calendars?

Other info: the Google calendars are a mix of read/write and read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Google Calendars won't sync with iCloud. The two are entirely unrelated services. However, you can do a couple of things as a pseudo work-around.

In one sense, if you have your Google Calendars on the iPad, they'll automatically sync with Google calendar and any other device that's configured to read the calendar.

Another option is to use something like [BusyCal](http://www.busymac.com/) to combine the Google and iCloud calendars. I wouldn't recommend this, as it's a much better idea to keep the data from the two services seperately.

Your main decision is to which will be your main calendar. It's solely a personal preference, as both calendars will largely give you the same functionality. If you prefer editing your calendars on the web, maybe stick with Google calendar. If you want to be able to share calendars with other iCloud users, move to iCloud calendars.

Comment: In my case, I want to view all the Exchange contacts; but the new ones I create, I want them to go to iCloud. Turning off the sync will prevent me from looking up the existing contacts from the Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings-> Mail, Contacts, Calendars and then under Contacts, select default Account to be "iCloud", instead of the Exchange.